# Are questions about jumping in a savefile and modifying it off topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

[How are ascendants (ancestors) ordered in Fallout Shelter save files?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/317450/how-are-ascendants-ancestors-ordered-in-fallout-shelter-save-files)

This question is currently flagged as off-topic, but i'm not sure it's written that questions about modifying a savefile are offtopic.

So are questions about jumping in a savefile and modifying it off topic? or does that question fail on another aspect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save-editing is not inherently off-topic. I'm sure I've seen questions in the past about it.

There are two potential issues. The first, which I believe the close voters mistakenly think is the case here, is the save file structure being considered developer intent. If the question is about accomplishing a specific task, developer intent is not relevant.

The second potential issue is that save-editing in a competitive, multiplayer game would run afoul of our policies on what cheating we do not help with.

Comment: Ok so maybe adding it as a note with developper intent?